# Python 2.7 Scrapy library fails to install "properly" on Yosemite

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

Okay so first things first, I haven't tried any other library installs on my Mac (running Yosemite V10.10) so that might be why I'm having trouble, but regardless I'm having difficulties running Scrapy. I've already figured out a few things, such as you need Python 2.7 to install it, which I have and when I type:

```
$ python -c 'import scrapy; print("%s.%s.%s" % scrapy.version_info)'
```

It returns 0.24.0 which seems like it's installed however I cannot use any commands. I was following a tutorial and the next line of code it asks for is to create this class:

```
import scrapy

class MinimalSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   """The smallest Scrapy-Spider in the world!"""
   name = 'minimal'
```

Which I do then to run this piece of code:

```
scrapy runspider minimal.py
```

Name of file is minimal.py and this returns a

```
scrapy: command not found error.
```

Now after a little bit of debugging, I switched tutorials to this one: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#intro-tutorial , however when I get to the first real piece of code and run:

```
scrapy startproject tutorial
```

it says the same thing.

My suspected resolution:
Now I've already checked and there is nothing in my "username"/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages folder - as this is where scrapy was supposed to have been downloaded, actually there's not even a Library folder, as I downloaded scrappy with the line pip install --user Scrapy==0.24 , so it saved it to my user folder, if I move one folder up and go to the main Library/Python/2.7 folder there's no lib file so I'm not really sure where Scrapy downloaded to. I'm not sure if this is causing my error, as I do think I have Scrapy installed.

Comment: virtualenv might be helpful to you http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: Hey Captain Murphy, do I have do familiarize myself with Homebrew? It still runs Python3 inside the Venv even though I've installed Python27 and require it to run scrapp. I've configured the shell to run without Python 2.7.8 OUTSIDE the venv...

Comment: You can specify what python to use in the virtualenv. This is the example in the link I shared previously: `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 venv`